# R "Multiple data sets per file"

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset like following:

```
0 0 0
0 0 0


54077 184965 81.25
54266 184776 81.25


65130 199986 82.1705426356589
65513 199600 82.1705426356589
```

those data were seperated by 2 blank lines. So when I use gnuplot to draw a dotplot, they will think those are seperated data in one file. How to do the same thing in R?? Because for each such dataset, I will have two points connected by lines. (eg, [5077,184965] connect to [54266, 199600])

Than you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also read the file into memory,

```
> buffer <- readLines ("tmp/file")
> buffer
 [1] "0 0 0"                         "0 0 0"                        
 [3] ""                              ""                             
 [5] "54077 184965 81.25"            "54266 184776 81.25"           
 [7] ""                              ""                             
 [9] "65130 199986 82.1705426356589" "65513 199600 82.1705426356589"
```

delete or process (e.g. derive measurement number, data set name, ...) all lines that somehow do not belong to the part of the file with the data tables:

```
> buffer <- buffer [nzchar (buffer) > 0L]
> buffer
[1] "0 0 0"                         "0 0 0"                        
[3] "54077 184965 81.25"            "54266 184776 81.25"           
[5] "65130 199986 82.1705426356589" "65513 199600 82.1705426356589"
```

and finally use `read.table` on the modified buffer:

```
> read.table (textConnection (buffer))
     V1     V2       V3
1     0      0  0.00000
2     0      0  0.00000
3 54077 184965 81.25000
4 54266 184776 81.25000
5 65130 199986 82.17054
6 65513 199600 82.17054
```

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts:

1. If they are all in the same format, then set the `blank.lines.skip` argument of `read.table`/`read.csv` to FALSE instead of its default TRUE.  Then you get a data.frame that has blank lines in it which you can split on.
2. If they are not all in the same format, then you can use the `skip` argument of those same commands to pull out only certain lines of the input file.

Answer (score 2):

Worst case scenario, you have to use readLines with n=1 to read a line at a time, splitting with strsplit, and collecting each data set in a list, looking for the separator (blank lines) before starting a new element of your list.

But you only need do that if gsk3's solutions fail because your dataset is a bit more unstructured...